# Parallelizing a function in differents ports using OpenMP without a barrier

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing, port, openmp

I want to run a function 96 times in parallel. The function runs a robot simulator server in a specified port.

In this program i run 24 threads 4 times. However, with a barrier, the program has to wait 24 threads to be finished in order to continue.

Knowing that threads have different execution times. When one takes a huge time, it will slow down the execution time.

Is there any other way to make all 96 threads (or robot servers) execute at once, taking on consideration ports disponibility dynamically?

```
int id=0;

for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
{
    #pragma omp parallel 
    {
        #pragma omp sections
        {
            #pragma omp section 
            {
                function(id, 11369);// id of the robot, port
            }
            #pragma omp section
            {
                function(id+1, 11370);
            }
            //...
            //...
            //...
            #pragma omp section
            {
                function(id+23, 11393);
            }
        }
        #pragma omp barrier
        #pragma omp single
        {
            id=id+24;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ...why not just `#pragma omp parallel for` and `for (int id = 0; id < 96; ++id) function(id)`? If you worry about execution times being very different then add `schedule(dynamic)` or `schedule(guided)`.

Comment: sections are for giving different threads different tasks to work on.  It's not at all clear why you aren't just running one `for` loop across `i=0..95`.

Comment: thanks for your reply... Actually each thread must run in a specific port, ex: 11369 to 11393... a thread is an instance of a robotic simulator server. i can not guarantee that it will be 96 free ports, so i choose specific ports.

Comment: @MaxLanghof has the right idea. You can set up an array containing the port numbers you want to service, then run a parallel for with each iteration taking the port number from the appropriate entry in the array (and, of course, choose the loop upper bound appropriately). But, none of these solutions will guarantee that all of your ports will be serviced at the same time.

Comment: The question is under specified. You must clearly state constraints you hint at in your comment in the question, otherwise we cannot give you a helpful answer.

Comment: thanks @JimCownie ports may not serviced at the same time, is it caused and depending on there disponibility ?